# If without else ternary operator

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator

So far from I have been searching through the net, the statement always have if and else condition such as `a ? b : c`. I would like to know whether the `if` ternary statement can be used without `else`. 
Assuming i have the following code, i wish to close the `PreparedStatement` if it is not null

(I am using Java programming language.)

```
PreparedStatement pstmt;

//.... 

(pstmt!=null) ? pstmt.close : <do nothing>;
```

Comment: The ternary operator is not equivalent to if/else. It's actually an expression that has to have a value.

Comment: You cannot use ternary without else, but you can use Java 8 `Optional` class: `Optional.ofNullable(pstmt).ifPresent(pstmt::close)`. See my answer below.

Comment: in place of your <do nothing> just put a variable with a value, like the number 0 or a string, it shouldn't do anything, although it does return a type, or even undefined or a null or void type MIGHT workm but also might cause an error in java

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[No, you cannot do that.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)
Instead try this:

```
if(bool1 && bool2) voidFunc1();
```

Answer (score 26):

Why using ternary operator when you have only one choice?

```
if (pstmt != null) pstmt.close();
```

is enough!

Answer (score 19):

Just write it out?

```
if(pstmt != null) pstmt.close();
```

It's the exact same length.

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in the other answers, you can't use a ternary operator to do this.

However, if the need strikes you, you can use Java 8 [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) and lambdas to put this kind of logic into a single statement:

```
Optional.of(pstmt).ifPresent((p) -> p.close())
```

Answer (score 16):

Ternary `if` operator is the particular *ternary operator*. One of a kind.

From [Wiki:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

> In mathematics, a ternary operation is an n-ary operation with n = 3.

It means all 3 operands are required for you.

Answer (score 12):

A ternary operation is called ternary beacause it takes 3 arguments, if it takes 2 it is a binary operation.

And as noted above, it is an **expression** returning a value.

If you omit the else you would have an undefined situation where the expression would not return a value.

So as also noted in other answer, you should use an if **statement**.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ternary without else, but to do a "if-without-else" in one line, you can use Java 8 `Optional` class.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt;

//.... 

Optional.ofNullable(pstmt).ifPresent(pstmt::close); // <- but IOException will still happen here. Handle it.
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
<logic Expression> ? <method> : null;
```

Example:

```
(pstmt!=null) ? pstmt.close : null;
```

is dirty solution but works...

Answer (score 0):

`pstmt != null && pstmt.close;`

The line of code above translates to When the left side of the expression "translates" to true -> execute the right side.

Answer (score -4):

Well in JavaScript you can simply do:

```
expression ? doAction() : undefined
```

since that's what's literally actually happening in a real if statement, the else clause is simply undefined. I image you can do pretty much the same thing in (almost?) any programming language, for the else clause just put a null-type variable that doesn't return a value, it shouldn't cause any compile errors.

or just make a function to return if all else fails

```
function oy(x1,x2){if(x1) return x2();}

oy(etzem==6, ()=>yichoyliss=8);
```

Comment: The question was about Java, not JS.