# How to "do nothing" in ternary operator in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is my code:

```
struct GameView : View {
    @State
    private var clicked1 : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Image("shape0")
                    .overlay(clicked1 ?
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:10)
                        .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 7) : pass()
                    )
                    .onTapGesure {
                        print("Image is clicked")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But some errors happen around `pass()`.

I want to do nothing when variable `clicked1` is `false`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If without else ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053257/if-without-else-ternary-operator)

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes This is not a Java question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.overlay` expects some View type as a parameter.

If you want to use a ternary operator, it has to return the same type. For a "do nothing" view, use `EmptyView()`, but since it has to be the same type, one way to do this would be by wrapping each conditional view with `AnyView`:

```
Image("shape0")
   .overlay(clicked1
            ? AnyView(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:10)
                         .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 7))
            : AnyView(EmptyView())
           )
```

**EDIT:**
Actually - `Optional<Wrapped: View>` also conforms to `View`, so this is a better approach than above - i.e. just return the view you want or `nil`:

```
Image("shape0")
   .overlay(clicked1 ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:10)
                         .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 7) : nil)
```

---

Another approach would be to use computed property which returns a conditional view:

```
var body: some View {
   Image("shape0")
      .overlay(overlayView)
}

@ViewBuilder
var overlayView: some View {
    if clicked1 {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:10)
                         .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 7)
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot parentheses - `AnyView(EmptyView())`

Comment: thanks for the Optional<Wrapped: View> conforming to View part. Now it makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

This would also work, the trick is to use `Group`.

Using ternary:

```
Image("shape0")
   .overlay(
       Group {
           clicked1 ?
               RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:10)
                   .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 7)
           : nil
       }
   )
```

Using if:

```
Image("shape0")
   .overlay(
       Group {
           if clicked1 { 
               RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:10)
                   .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 7)
           }
       }
   )
```

Comment: This reminded me that `Optional<Wrapped: View> : View` - i.e. an optional view is a view, so no need for `Group`